# My front tooth fell out after a fall, dentist put it back in...?

Tags: dentistry, surgery

Has anyone had this happen where the dentist put it back in? He told me he would see whether my body rejects it or not and than he would do a root canal and put a crown. What are the chances my body rejects this? (I kept the tooth in milk by the way until I went to the dentists) he have me some steroids and some growth stimulants to help with healing.

Comment: It happens all the time, and is the recommended practice in certain circumstances. Are you asking for someone to share their experience with you, if this is an accepted practice, what the outcomes are, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want someone to share their experience and how long it took to heal, the process, etc...

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). As per [help] personal experiences and opinions are not on topic here, but you can [edit] your question to ask about scientific studies and, as anongoodnurse suggested, whether this is an accepted practice and what the possible outcomes (and their probabilities if such research exists) are. That would prevent your question from being closed.